# How do I get UISearchController to work with the UISearchBar Interface Builder control?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

**List item**

How do I get a UISearchController to work with the search bar control in Interface Builder? I have tried the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!  

searchController.searchBar = searchBar
```

This gives me an error during coding time saying that searchController.searchBar is a get-only property.

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!  

searchBar = searchController.searchBar
```

This gives me the UI I want, but the search doesn't work.

```
var searchBar: UISearchBar!  

searchBar = searchController.searchBar  

NSLayoutConstraint(searchBar, ..... )
```

This works, except that when I start typing in the search bar, the search bar disappears.**

Comment: I'm also have same problem

Answer (score 0):

UISearchController's searchBar is a computed property, so you have to store your custom searchBar and return it when you call searchBar.

```
var yourSearchBar = yourSearchBar()
override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    get{
        return yourSearchBar;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that. I get an error saying, "Property does not override any property from its superclass" on the line where I override. I assume you meant for me to write an extension for UISearchController.